# How to check for real equality (of numpy arrays) in python?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, ipopt

I have some function in python returning a numpy.array:

```
matrix = np.array([0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,1.,1.,0.],
             [0.,0.,0.,1.,1.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.])

def some_function:
    rows1, cols1 = numpy.nonzero(matrix)
    cols2 = numpy.array([6,7,8,3,4,7])
    rows2 = numpy.array([0,0,0,1,1,1])
    print numpy.array_equal(rows1, rows2) # returns True
    print numpy.array_equal(cols1, cols2) # returns True
    return (rows1, cols1)                   # or (rows2, cols2)
```

It should normally extract the indices of nonzero entries of a matrix (rows1, cols1). However, I can also extract the indices manually (rows2, cols2). The problem is that the program returns different results depending on whether the function returns `(rows1, cols1)` or `(rows2, cols2)`, although the arrays should be equal.

I should probably add that this code is used in the context of *pyipopt*, which calls a c++ software package *IPOPT*. The problem then occurs within this package.

Can it be that the arrays are not "completely" equal? I would say that they somehow must be because I am not modifying anything but returning one instead of the other.

Any idea on how to debug this problem?

Comment: `nonzeros` isn't a thing, did you mean `nonzero`? Also, can you include some sample `matrix` so we can replicate the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `nonzero`. I also added a sample matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You could check [where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) the arrays are not equal:

```
print(where(rows1 != rows2))
```

But what you are doing is unclear, first there is no `nonzeros` function in numpy, only a [nonzero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) which returns a tuple of coordinates. Are you only using the one corresponding to the rows?

Comment: Sorry, indeed, I meant `nonzero`. I am using rows and columns; I changed the sample code for clarity.